# Tools for crawling ActiveRecord relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I've got a situation where I need to pull some data from prod to staging - let's say, a `MagazineSubscription`. But I'll need to include *all* the related records, particularly those that must exist for validation to pass - let's say, `Magazine`, `Issue`, `Publisher`, `User`, `UserAddress`, etc.

I've been google'ing around, but either there isn't anything (which I'm a little surprised about), or I'm not using the right terms (crawl, relations).

Are there any existing tools for doing this, and/or are there more-correct search terms for finding what exists?

(Currently, going to explore `ActiveRecord` introspection to detect and follow relationships)

Comment: Do you have foreign keys in your database?

Comment: Yep, lots. Pretty sure we've got at least one of all possible relations; `has_one`, `has_many`, `belongs_to`, `has_and_belongs_to_many` in both flavors (with and without an ActiveRecord model for the join table). I don't think there's any places where the Rails validation requires the relation but the database doesn't, although there's definitely places where the data won't make any sense without some related record, but will pass validation.

Comment: Is this job really so extensive that you need to automate the task of finding the assocations / foreign key constraints? To me it just sounds like you need to analyze the schema and models and write a rake task or active job that mirrors the data.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1319/ except "easy enough the first time, but after three you're really wishing you had some automation", and there's no way I'm the only one with this need in the broader community. *Personally*, I've wanted a tool that does this at every job I've ever had. Also note that I'm not actually trying to mirror *all* the data, I'm trying to slice out a contiguous chunk.

Comment: Maybe try looking for a database-specific solution. Might have better luck with SQL.

Comment: @muistooshort good thinking, but still no luck :/ Export/dump seem to be the verb, but either I'm not finding a way to describe "and all relations / foreign keys", or it still doesn't exist. There's plenty for "entire table" / "entire database", but none for this kind of cohesive slice.

Comment: I don't actually think it exists. While you can walk the associations or foreign keys creating something that actually understands how your domain is connected in a meaningful way is a very tough nut to crack. Then you have to deal with issues like how you're going to handle reinserting the data with different primary keys and in an order that doesn't violate any foreign key constraints. Its a non-trivial problem thats very hard to solve in a universal way.

Comment: I don't think that really exists. You can have a lot of custom validations or smth like that and it can be a problem. I think you can write the script and save records as a seed file. Then seed into your DB.